# ASP.net swf game file preview (thumbnail)

Tags: asp.net, ffmpeg, flash, thumbnails

**Scenario**:

I really in need for your help.
I have multiple swf game files which I want to view them on the page as thumbnails and let the visitor click on it to play the game.

**Required:**

I want a tool that let make take a thumbnail from swf file, maybe the first frame of the file as image to view it.

maybe if there another way to preview the files in asp.net pages without the need to the following way could be better.

**Bad news**

I have viewed all the possible answers on StackOverFlow and even on Google but with no luck, they lead my to the following:

- use: https://swf.codeplex.com/: I have tried it and now result
- use ffmpeg: but the feature is not available yet, and I'm getting the following error 
  'swf: could not find codec parameters'

Comment: How many such games do you have? Can't you just run each game and take a snapshot? Even using a tool to automatically extract snapshots of your games, most probably the images taken won't be as illustrative as a snapshot taken during gameplay itself. No tool can play a demo of each game and take a picture of it (although I heard Google was in the making of some AI that could play arcade games without instructions). Even more: feature graphics do not necessarily depict exact scenes from featured games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used   to view the SWF file and make a div overlay to stop user interaction with it, after that I have made the div clickable so the user will navigate to the file page

```
<div style="cursor: pointer; position: relative; z-index: 1">
    <div id="overlay" onclick="window.location.href='Game.aspx?gameId=7'; return false;" style="opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;     right: 0; display: block; z-index: 2; background-color: red">
    </div>
    <object data="Handler.ashx?gameId=7" width="250" height="200"></object>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out swfextract, part of swftools. It's a console app so you can easily drive it from your own software.

Comment: this tool used to  extracting data out of swf files, alternatively I want to take a snapshot as image from any frame of the swf file to use it as thumbnail