# ASP.net make object clickable

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, .net, flash

I have a flash object as following

```
<object data="http://www.learnenglish.org.uk/kids/antics/monkey.swf" width="250" height="200"></object>
```

I want to make the flash file clickable without letting the flash play,  so when the user click in its area navigate to the page that display it.

Comment: do that with a simple anchor, and an image.

Comment: @Aristos sorry I don't have the image and I can't add it. thanks for comment

Answer (score 2):

Take a screenshot of your Flash file, some frame you think best represents the file. Perhaps use an image editor to add a title or other graphic.

Then you have the image, wrapped in an anchor:

```
<a href='/path/to/page/of/flash/file/'>
  <img src='/path/to/image' />
</a>
```

Comment: Actually I have a dynamic website, so the user can only upload the game file, I have heard about div overlay so I can make div over div and make the second div clickable but I don't know who to apply this approach.

Comment: @Moatasembk Well, you can allow the user to upload their own screenshots (best option, and use a stock placeholder if they don't provide a screenshot). Or you can try to process the file on the server and generate an image. I don't think overlaying the flash is going to be a good use of resources.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, the provided database doesn't allow  uploading additional info like image, I have tried to manipulate the flash file and get the first frame but with no luck, I have tried swfdotnet and ffmpeg, but both doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Moatasembk So modify the database? Or ask a new question about how to obtain the image using one of those libraries (including the code you attempted)?

Comment: modifying the database is not my work, in according to the second question I have did that before..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29417337/asp-net-swf-game-file-preview-thumbnail

Comment: @Moatasembk You asked it before yes, but you didn't do what I said where you should make an attempt and include that code. We're not a code writing service. If you just people to write your code for you, then hire a contractor. We're here to help programmers with their problems, which means you need to put effort into solving it and *show your work*.

Comment: actually I just need a way to apply my approach, I can do a workaround by adding a navigation button under the object and make the flash file unplayable, I'm not looking for people coding instead of me, I'm just presenting my problem to build up my knowledge !!.

Answer (score 0):

I have done what I want by using Div overlay

```
<div style="cursor: copy; position: relative; z-index: 1">   
   <div id="overlay" onclick="window.alert('hi')" style="opacity: 0; sition: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; display: block; z-index: 2; background-color: red">
   </div>
   <object data="Handler.ashx?gameId" width="250" height="200"></object>
</div>
```

If anyone have another solution please post it.